# Balanced Payments - Documentation on obtaining references to existing buyer and merchant accounts

Tags: ruby, balanced-payments

How would I get a reference to buyer and merchant accounts that have already been created?

I'm only finding examples for creating buyer and merchant accounts. I'm not finding any examples on getting that information back for reuse. Is there existing documentation on this or just what's in the rdoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the reference to rdoc I'll assume you're using the Ruby gem here.

There are two primary ways to lookup accounts using a unique identifier, by `email_address`:

```
account = Balanced::Account.find_by_email(email_address)
```

or by `URI`:

```
account = Balanced::Account.find(account_uri)
```

All resources within Balanced are referenced primarily by URI so you can do something like `Balanced::Credit.find(credit_uri)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This has been deprecated instead now you now use Balanced::Customer.find_by_email(email_address)