# Reference existing buyers and merchants with Balanced

Tags: php, balanced-payments

I was looking over the question ([obtaining references to existing buyer and merchant accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588911/balanced-payments-documentation-on-obtaining-references-to-existing-buyer-and)), which asked how to reference an account by email for ruby and was wondering how to do the same with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to look up an account by email address in PHP using the [balanced-php](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php) library:

```
$buyer = $marketplace->accounts->query()->filter(Balanced\Account::$f->email_address->eq("buyer2@example.org"))->one();
```

You can see how to look up an existing account by URI if you look at the [example.php](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/example/example.php#L114) file included with the balanced-php library:

```
print "how do we look up an existing object from the URI?\n";
$the_buyer = Balanced\Account::get($buyer->uri);
print "we got the buyer " . $the_buyer->email_address . "\n";
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had seen the uri but couldn't figure the email one.